# Excel Data Validation -Disable cell in excel based on drop down value

Tags: excel, validation

I have 2 columns in an Excel sheet. `A1` contains a drop down with the values "Enable" and "Disable". Cell B1 and C1 needs to be enabled or disabled based on the `A1` drop down selection.

I tried using Data Validation but it does not work. Can anyone suggest how I might use Data Validation to accomplish this?

```
          A     |   B
------------------------
1       Suggestions| (This cell should disable (B1))
------------------------
2       Errors| (Now here drop down will come with values(B2))
------------------------
```

Current VBA

```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     ThisRow = Target.Row
      If Target = Range("A1") Then
           If Target.Value = "Suggestions" Then
                Worksheets("Code Review").Range("B:C").Locked = True
            End If
      Else
         Worksheets("Code Review").Range("B:C").Locked = False
      End If 
     End Sub
```

Also tried like this

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cel As Range
    If Not Intersect(Range("A:A"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Me.Unprotect
    For Each cel In Intersect(Range("A:A"), Target)
        cel.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Resize(ColumnSize:=2).Locked = _
        cel.Value = "Suggestion"
    Next cel
    Me.Protect
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
```

But this locks everything :( I want just 2 cells to be locked.

Comment: Could you give an example of possibilities you want to obtain?

Comment: @Jerry: updated the post. But formatting issue.

Comment: Thank you, and that's okay. It does make things clearer :)

Comment: Thanks Jerry. I dont want user to edit the cell when he select the "Disable" in drop down. I already written formula to load the drop box . Help me :(

Comment: What do you mean by cell b1 needs to be enabled/disabled?  Do you mean locked and protected?

Comment: Hi Dean, User should not able to edit the value in the cell. I am new to excel and do not know difference between locked and protected. I simply want to make cell NON-EDITABLE